# Concatenate distinct strings in to a new column, partitioned by an ID?

Tags: powerbi, concatenation, grouping, dax, partitioning

Example input:

| ID | Enjoys |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | Coke |
| Alice | Biscuits |
| Alice | Lemonade |
| Bob | Coke |
| Bob | Apples |
| Bob | Apples |
| Charlie | Milk |

Desired output:

| ID | New Col |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | CokeBiscuitsLemonade |
| Bob | CokeApples |
| Charlie | Milk |

What I've been trying so far is

```
CONCATENATEX
(
    SUMMARIZE(
              INPUT_TABLE,
              'INPUT_TABLE'[ID],
              'INPUT_TABLE'[Enjoys],
             )
    DISTINCT('INPUT_TABLE'[Enjoys])
)
```

but this is a syntax error. As for using

```
CONCATENATEX
(
    DISTINCT(SUMMARIZE(
              INPUT_TABLE,
              'INPUT_TABLE'[ID],
              'INPUT_TABLE'[Enjoys],
             ))
    'INPUT_TABLE'[Enjoys]
)
```

this seems to forget that I'm trying to partition by ID. In this case, I suspect that it would return "CokeBiscuitsLemonadeApplesMilk" on every row.

What is the correct DAX for obtaining this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
NewTable = 
SUMMARIZE(INPUT_TABLE,INPUT_TABLE[ID],"concat",CONCATENATEX(DISTINCT(INPUT_TABLE[Enjoys]),INPUT_TABLE[Enjoys]))
```

To add it as a measure:

```
CONCATENATEX(distinct(FILTER(selectcolumns(allselected(INPUT_TABLE),"ID",INPUT_TABLE[ID],"Enjoys",INPUT_TABLE[Enjoys]),[ID] = selectedvalue(INPUT_TABLE[ID]))),[Enjoys])
```

This measure works even if you have more than these 2 columns in your INPUT_TABLE

Comment: This doesn't force the "Enjoys" parts to be distinct.

Comment: I have updated the answer to take the distinct values

Comment: Great! That looks to be right. Is it possible to do this as a new column rather than a new table?

Comment: You can do it as a measure (not a column). i have added the corresponding dax in the answer

Comment: The measure works like a charm. If you have two ID columns, just add another line in the `selectcolumns` function for it and then `&& [ID2] = selectedvalue()` in the filter function.